# Compiling Jython From Source generate org.python.parser directory

Tags: java, python, jython

Hello I am trying to compile the Jython Java Source Code from subversion. But it fails because there is no parser directory it should be org.python.parser in org/python/parser. I read that this folder you need to generate. Any ideas how would be great!

I found this link but its very dated and doesn't seem to explain anything at all

http://www.jython.org/archive/21/docs/compile.html

Answer (score 1):

The [Jython Developer Guide](http://wiki.python.org/jython/JythonDeveloperGuide) is what you need.  You should just able to run `ant` in the top-level directory to compile it.